# MacBook Pro Certificate - no value specified - Business Category : Private Organization

Tags: macbook-pro, security, internet, certificate

Today after I signed into my computer and opened Safari this window popped up: [image: Pop up message about certificate]

[image: information about the pop up message about the certivicate]

I am looking for help to know what this is, and what I need to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

It’s perfectly normal, and there’s no need to do anything (except click on OK to close the window) or worry about it. Safari is just showing you the encryption details for the apple.com website — you may have accidentally clicked on the green padlock.

Comment: I checked clicking on the green padlock, you were Correct! Thank you!